# How to make Spring Integration FTP Inbound Channel Adapter's local filter use the remote filter as default

Tags: spring-integration

For Spring Integration FTP Inbound Channel Adapter, if I don't explicitly set the `local-filter`, is it possible to use the remote filter's value as default?

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="myChannel"
                                     channel="nullChannel"
                                     session-factory="cachingSessionFactory"
                                     filename-pattern="abc_2017*.txt"
                                     remote-directory="/"
                                     preserve-timestamp="true"
                                     local-directory="c:/temp">
    <int:poller cron="15 * * * * ?" max-messages-per-poll="-11" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

e.g. In my use case, the remote directory contains `abc_201701.txt`, `abc_201702.txt` etc, the pattern `filename-pattern="abc_2017*.txt"` will let me successfully download all these files. However, if my local directory contains additonal file, say, `def.txt`, all 3 files `abc_201701.txt`, `abc_201702.txt` and `def.txt` `Message`s will be generated.

I think it makes more sense if the local-filter will respect the remote filter by default (if I don't explicitly set), i.e. only 2 messages `abc_201701.txt`and `abc_201702.txt` will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this suggestion is confusing. The remote filter is based on the remote entity, but local on the `File` object. Plus we have there `localFilenameGeneratorExpression` where the local name may become non-relevant to the remote, therefore any copying `filename-pattern` to the local version would be odd. Also this idea has strong limitation only with name based filters. That is clearly described in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound) why we need `local-filter` and how `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` is used by default.

OTOH that's not Framework responsibility to deal with unexpected content in the `local-directory`. The local part is just regular `FileReadingMessageSource` - http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading. So, that is pretty natural for it to expect any files in the directory.

You should consider to clean the directory before during starting your app or come up with some local filter which won't pick those suspicious files.

Comment: Agree - deleted my answer.

Comment: Why I raise this question is related to my use case. I have 1 remote file in ftp which is keep updating. For each polling, I will download the file and trigger the diff program to generate the delta file (maybe suffix the filename with timestamp), stored it in the same directory of the download directory. If I don't set the local-filter, the FileReadingMessageSource will repeatedly generate the delta file and suffix with timestamp (not just the generation of delta based on the remote ftp file). i.e. abc.txt.20170626, abc.txt.20170626.20170626, abc.txt.20170626.20170626.20170626 etc

Comment: As a common SI user, I might only configure subset of <int:ftp /> attributes. I might expect that if I just set the filename-pattern and download the file (i.e. not setting local-fitler), the generation of events would be the same of the files downloaded. That's why I ask whether the lcoal-filter should respect the remote file-filter as default to avoid surprise. Anyway, I agree with what Artem's explanation.

Comment: Well, that is your use-case. And it doesn't look trivial. So, what is the problem to follow with existing recommendation and specify an appropriate local filter, even if it may have the same pattern semantics? As I said: you are just unlucky that your logic is based on the pattern which feels like inheritance-capable, but the problem is a bit broader and in case of Java Configuration we have to specify `FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter` for remote part and `SimplePatternFileListFilter` for local.